# Insert a record into 2 tables in SQL Server using comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 table A and table B; table B is linked to table A through a foreign key.

`TABLE A` has a structure somewhat like this

```
PK Id
DeliveryChannelValue
DeliverychannelId
Date time
```

`Table B` has this structure

```
PK Id UniqueIdentifiers
Date time 
FK tableA id
```

Now in a stored procedure, I get unique identifiers as comma separated value, so based on the number of items in that list, I have to create the same number of rows in table A and in table B.

If the number of items in comma separated value is 3, then there will be 3 rows to be inserted into table A and 3 rows into table B. I am trying to avoid a cursor.

Please suggest efficient way to do this.

Comment: have you considered using triggers?

Comment: You need to use a transaction and two insert statements.  No cursor should be needed, but a function which converts a comma separated list to a table will help.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 r2 I parsed the comma separated value  and inserted into temp table and then trying to do insert the record in table A problem is how will I get the identity of record inserted in table A for every item.

Comment: With the OUTPUT clause you can retrieve the inserted values. Take a look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: On 2008 R2 you will be better off using table valued parameters than splitting comma delimited lists. For the other question you just asked you can use  the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Google for "SQL Server Split function".  The good ones do not have cursors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666620/T-SQL-Most-Practical-Split-Function) split function to separate the values, and then use a known DateTime stamp to keep the tables in sync. This assumes these values aren't constantly updating which could cause a DateTime duplication issue: if that's the case, you'll need to use a add a GUID value in place of the YOURDATE field, below:

```
DECLARE @DATESTAMP DATETIME = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (ID, YOURDATE)
SELECT item, @DATESTAMP
FROM dbo.[FN_SPLIT](@yourinputstring)

GO

INSERT INTO TABLE_B(YOURDATE, TABLE_A_ID)
SELECT @DATESTAMP, ID
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE YOURDATE = @DATESTAMP

GO
```